# JPA , Spring Mapping multiple entities

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate-mapping

I have 3 tables Consultant, Patient and Diagnosis. Diagnosis has attributes of both Consultant and Patient as foreign keys. I want to know how to show this in spring. What i have so far is,
`Consultant.java`

```
   private String name;
   private String pos;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "consultant")
    private List<Diagnosis> diagnosis;
```

`Diagnosis.java`

```
public class Request {
    private String token;
    private String comment;
    private boolean status;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "Patient_id")
    @JoinColumn(name = "Consultant_id") //not sure about this syntax
    private Consultant consultant;
    private Patient patient;
```

`Patient.java`

```
 private String name;
   private int pid;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "patient")
    private List<Diagnosis> diagnosis;
```

Please is this how to go about it? I'm using postgresql.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you annotating one field if you have 2 entities? Every relationship should be properly annotated:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "Patient_id")
private Patient patient;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "Consultant_id")
private Consultant consultant;
```